# Chlorination by SOCl2 vs SO2Cl2

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

My textbook mentions that chlorination of alkanes by $\ce{SO2Cl2}$ is preferred over $\ce{SOCl2}$, but I didn't understand why.

Could someone explain which of the two reagents I should use in what situations, and briefly tell me why?

There is a similar question here: 
[How does SO2Cl2 react with alcohols?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33430/21838)

However the answers there did not completely clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reactivity patterns of $\ce{SO2Cl2}$ and $\ce{SOCl2}$ are quite different. $\ce{SOCl2}$ is a good electrophile, and can be thought of as a source of $\ce{Cl-}$ ions.  These ions can go on to react in their typical nucleophilic fashion. $\ce{SO2Cl2}$ however is often a $\ce{Cl2}$ source, as it readily decomposes giving off sulfur dioxide. Usually much easier/safer to use this than measuring out (and getting into solution) chlorine gas. The chlorination of simple alkanes by $\ce{Cl2}$ gas (or something that makes it in solution) happens by a radical mechanism i.e. $\ce{Cl.}$ not $\ce{Cl-}$.

Comment: A solid answer.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the precise answer. So the major difference is socl2 reacts by nucleophilic substitution, but so2cl2 reacts by free radical mechanism, right?

Comment: I would say that the major difference is the oxidation state of the Cl formed. As stated in the answer, SOCl2 is a source of *chloride ions* whereas SO2Cl2 is a source of *chlorine*. That is a consequence of the different **reactivity** of the two species (SOCl2 is an electrophile and SO2Cl2 decomposes into SO2 + Cl2) I'm just restating the answer... my goodness.

Answer (score 3):

Chlorination of **alkanes** by $\ce{SO2Cl2}$ is preferred over $\ce{SOCl2}$. Just pay little more attention on the word alkanes. So, the statement is absolutely correct. 
Just go through it ([link](http://www.chemistry.mtu.edu/pages/courses/organic/manuals/2411/FreeRad/FreeRad08.pdf))!
Hence, For chlorination in alkanes, if you use $\ce{SO2Cl2}$, It undergoes a free radical substitution reaction and will get the product.

---

If we use $\ce{SOCl2}$, it undergoes a nucleophilic substitution reaction. [Here](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/02/10/socl2-and-the-sni-mechanism/), this reaction mechanism is explained.

So, You can see here that $\ce{SOCl2}$ doesn't produce a chlorine free radical. Hence, It is not possible to chlorinate alkanes using $\ce{SOCl2}$, which $\ce{SO2Cl2}$ does.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation " latex="" ‎at="" chem.se""="), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/7448) and [this ‎one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/111/7448) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: Oh! That makes a lot of sense. A nucleophile wouldn't be able to attack an alkane, right? Thanks a lot!!